# How can I group multiple e-mail addresses and user names using a regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, regex

I have the following text that I am trying to parse:

```
"user1@emailaddy1.com" <user1@emailaddy1.com>, "Jane Doe" <jane.doe@ addyB.org>,
"joe@company.net" <joe@company.net>
```

I am using the following code to try and split up the string:

```
Dim groups As GroupCollection
Dim matches As MatchCollection
Dim regexp1 As New Regex("""(.*)"" <(.*)>")
matches = regexp1 .Matches(toNode.InnerText)
For Each match As Match In matches
    groups = match.Groups
    message.CompanyName = groups(1).Value
    message.CompanyEmail = groups(2).Value
Next
```

But this regular expression is greedy and is grabbing the entire string up to the last quote after "joe@company.net".  I'm having a hard time putting together an expression that will group this string into the two groups I'm looking for:  Name (in the quotes) and E-Mail (in the angle brackets).  Does anybody have any advice or suggestions for altering the regexp to get what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than rolling your own regular expression, I would do this:

```
string[] addresses = toNode.InnerText.Split(",");
foreach(string textAddress in addresses)
{
    textAddress = address.Trim();
    MailAddress address = new MailAddress(textAddress);
    message.CompanyName = address.DisplayName;
    message.CompanyEmail = address.Address;
}
```

While your regular expression may work for the few test cases that you have shown.  Using the `MailAddress` class will probably be much more reliable in the long run.

Comment: Didn't even THINK about doing this!!

Comment: This method works really well as long as a DisplayName isn't "Doe, Jane"...  do you have any suggestions on how to modify this method for those special PITA cases?

Comment: I don't have a simple answer to this, unfortunately ... but it appears that this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047531/splitting-comma-seperated-values-csv/1047670#1047670) suggests using the TextFieldParser class for comma-delimited stuff.

Comment: I ended up cheating a little bit - but hopefully it will keep things reliable.  I added this line before the split: Dim seps() as String = {", <", ">, """} and changed the split line to: Dim addresses() as String = toNode.InnerText.Split(seps, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Answer (score 1):

How about `"""([^""]*)"" <([^>]*)>"` for the regex? I.e. make explicit that the matched part won't include a quote/closing paren. You may also want to use a more restrictive character-range instead.

Comment: The first part should be `""([^""]*)""`, not `""([^)]*)""`.

Comment: Yes, of course. I confused myself with all that punctuation ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that you want the minimal matched expression.
You can also replace (.*) pattern by more precise ones: 
For example you could exclude the comma and the space...
Usually it's better to avoid using .* in a regular expression, because it reduces performance !

For example for the email, you can use a pattern like [\w-]+@([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+ or a more complex one.
You can find some good patterns on : http://regexlib.com/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what regexp engine ASP.net is running but try the non-greedy variant by adding a ? in the regex.

Example regex

```
""(.*?)"" <(.*?)>
```