# Read CSV in C# .NET without inputting field names

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I need to read a CSV file for use as an array in C# .NET framework. The equivalent of e.g.

```
var animalList = new List<Animal>()
{
    new Animal{Name = "German Shepherd",
    Height = 25,
    Weight = 77},
    new Animal{Name = "Chihuahua",
    Height = 7,
    Weight = 4.4},
};
```

But stored and read from a CSV file with columns `Name`,`Height`,`Weight`. I can see methods to do this with and without packages online, e.g. with the [Lumen CSV Reader](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-read-data-from-csv-file-in-c-sharp/) package. However, I have two issues:

1. Ideally I'd like to do this without installing anything (like the Lumen CSV Reader package)
2. My CSV has thousands of fields, so the part where

```
public class SearchParameters  
    {  
        public string FirstName{ get; set; }  
        public string LastName{ get; set; }  
        public string Email{ get; set; }  
    }
```

is written in the tutorial is impractical, as I don't want to write out all the field names. I would like to just read them from the header of the CSV. Anyone know how to do this?

The CSV files are pretty large (up to around 1,000 columns and 20,000 rows - most elements are Boolean: True or False). Reading them in doesn't have to be the most efficient thing in the world (but I will need the final array to be queried by System.LINQ with maximum speed).

Comment: `Ideally I'd like to do this without installing anything` - why? Why must you reinvent the wheel? Isn't it a lot more prudent to take advantage of the work others have done? Must you make the same mistakes all over again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting Comma Separated Values (CSV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047531/splitting-comma-separated-values-csv)

Comment: `Ideally I'd like to do this without installing anything` please just use the tools provided, whenever possible, instead of rolling your own, potentially creating yet another broken implementation.

Comment: https://www.withoutbugs.com/2011/06/top-6-ways-to-parse-csv-high.html

Comment: @FranzGleichmann what exactly are 'the tools provided'?

Comment: @mason The main reason is I don't want to install unnecessary items. If there is some package whose only purpose is to read CSVs, and it is accordingly extremely lightweight, that would be fine. But as far as I can see ```Lumen CSV Reader``` still has the problem I mentioned above (having to manually type the fields)

Comment: @MobeusZoom the _huge_ number of libraries that are publicly available for everyone, doing exactly what you want to do.

Comment: @MobeusZoom It's not unnecessary if it's doing a job for you. Not just doing a job, but far better than you can or have time for. Your job isn't to write CSV parsers is it? That's someone else's job. So don't do their job: they've already done it, and fixed a lot of bugs and had a lot of other people [dogfooding](https://newrepublic.com/article/115349) for you. I don't know about Lumen, never used it. The standard go-to package for CSV in .NET is [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/).

Comment: As for why you don't want to define a class to represent your data, why not? It would be trivial to generate a class with the necessary properties. It's something you'd only have to do once, and a few lines of C# can create the necessary properties for you. So what specifically is your aversion to it? You are dismissing tools and techniques without providing a solid justification for doing so: that's just going to make life harder on you.

Comment: @mason I'm happy to define the class, just not every field individually. There are thousands and they have different names between the different CSVs I need to load, so I cannot write out the names one-by-one as in the example above

Comment: Do you need every single field? Or just specific ones? Are these CSV's standardized, such that you have multiple types, and each type is consistent in the columns that it uses?

Comment: Write a tool that parses the first line of your CSV file (and ignores everything after the first end-of-line).  Generally, the first line of the CSV file has fewer of the weirdnesses that make CSV parsing _interesting_.  Us that data to create your class.  You really don't want to write your own CSV parser.  They look simple, but they are not.

Comment: I have a way to do this, that would allow you to drop a csv into your project and not have to write any special code at all to access it; just call MyCsvFile.Read().ToArray(), and use linq to objects on strongly typed representation of your data. Unfortunately it requires installing nuget packages, bummer.

Comment: @mason yes, we need every field. The type of every field is a boolean (True/False).

Comment: @Flydog57 so do you recommend then copying & pasting that into a .cs file (even though it'll have thousands of lines just for field names)?

Comment: Sure, why not? C# classes can have lots of properties. As long as you build tooling to manage it, it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: No, not copying/pasting.  Write a simple little program that reads the first line of your CSV file and writes out a full .CS file that includes all your code. (`public class Whatever { public string Prop1 { get; set; } ...`.  To some extent that's kinda-sorta how a lot of the auto-generated code that VS produces is created (kinda-sorta)

Answer (score 0):

Some packages do allow for working on the csv file with some kind of a record type, that you can then read by index/header-name (cannot find the one I remember). But considering the size of the input, I am unsure how regular csv deserializers will perform.

Please consider, that if there is no underlying class to represent a record, then at some point you will have to tell the code what type to use (each time you access a property). You *could* write a (for example) python script, that based on the first two lines creates the *.cs file for the class, and you compile it into the project.

Regarding not using any packages... well you could write some simple code, where you split the line. If it is guaranteed, that none of the fields contain a comma (or the separator) and a linebreak, it could work - but you still have to write a dynamic program, that matches csv records with a property and somehow finds a proper deserializer for that type. I would strongly suggest using a library for this, like [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/).

*As a **sidenote**, if you are willing to consider alternatives, I would load this thing into a key-value database (you can simulate it with an RDBMS, though it wont be super fast). It might be easier to work with SQL.*

TL;DR

- option 1: generate a class with a script and then use a nuget package to handle the serialization (kind of the 'spray and pray' method) - linq will be available like normal
- option 2: use a database, that is more prepared for large datasets

Comment: Thanks for the considered reply. I thought of using a database but the linkup (we will receive C# input which guides the SQL query, and have to feed the response back to C#, all in real-time) seemed like a lot of work. We're planning to prototype for which a much smaller dataframe can be used (something like 20 rows by 100 columns). The format is very regular (every column except the first is just T or F). I can get this out of Pandas any way I like (doesn't have to be csv). What would you recommend as the lightest-weight option for getting it into C#?

Comment: @MobeusZoom Sorry for being late. First. For a prototype I would go full-on hacky and generate the properties (the c# source code) with python, then load the data as csv. Also you may want to consider things like storing the boolean values in a dictionary or a KV array. 

Is a production solution part of this question? If yes, how would you have to access the input (non-parameter) there (getting it in c# or opening a file etc)?

Comment: 'generate the properties' Do you mean the code in tutorials above, but using Python to automate printing out column rows, and just copying and pasting that into a .cs from which I load the data as csv? Do you recommend CsvHelper? As for storage, it's currently in Pandas dataframes, but what would you recommend? The solution does need to be integrated in the rest of our prototype, where the input will come as a variable in C# and the output from the query will be used in C# too

Comment: something like `props = [F'public bool {col} {{ get; set; }} ' for col in file.readline().split(',')]`
 and then you paste it in a class. First column as you said will be string, well change its type by hand.

I have not used any csv package with this large amount of data, but go ahead and try csv helper. 

The benefit of this hacky way is that you will already have a class to represent your data later.